# find element by it's attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('area-expanded')
});
```

will return an array of links with attribute called `'area-expanded'`.

I need to find a link, whose attribute `'area-expanded'` value is `true` (there is always one such link on the page).

I tried the following:

```
$('a').filter(function(){return $(this).attr('area-expanded').val() == true});
```

but I am getting

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`

I'm complete noob in JS so I am sure there is something simle I am missing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attribute-value](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```
$('a[area-expanded="true"]')
```

This will select all the `<a>` whose `aria-expanded` attribute value is set to  `true`.